# javax.net.ssl.SSLContext to io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext

Tags: java, ssl, sslcontext

How should one convert `javax.net.ssl.SSLContext` to `io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext` ? I have access to SSLContext but need to set SSlContext in my client library.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried [`io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/ssl/JdkSslContext.html) yet, which seems to accept a pre-configured `javax.net.ssl.SSLContext`?

Comment: I checked it but I was not sure if there are any caveats.

Comment: Looks like there has been an issue/improvement some time ago, which were resolved in current versions. Also, looking into the code (via Grepcode) seems to reveal some mismatch to the API docs.